# Serialize related objects in django rest framework

Tags: django, rest, python-2.7, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

How can I serialize related objects in DRF. Am having three models auth_user (User), ModelA, ModelB.

My models:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(auth_user, related_name = 'modelA')
  name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)

class ModelB(models.Model):
  owner = models.OneToOneField(auth_user)
  user = models.OneToOneField(auth_user, related_name = 'modelB')
  type = models.ForeignKey(ModelD)
  cost = models.IntegerField()

class ModelD(models.Model):
  type_desc = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
```

My serialilzers:

```
class A(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   class Meta:
    model = ModelA
    fields = ('name', )

class B(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  class Meta:
     model = ModelB
     fields = ('type', 'cost', )

class AuthUserSerilaizer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  userA = serializers.RelatedField(source = 'modelA')
  userB = serializers.RelatedField(source = 'modelB')

  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('email', 'password', 'userA', 'userB', )
    write_only_fields = ('password',)

  @transaction.commit_manually 
  def restore_object(self, attrs, instance = None):

     try:
         user = User.objects.create_user(email = attrs.get('email'), password =   attrs.get('password'))
        modela = ModelA(user =user, name = attrs.get('name'))
        modela.save()
        transaction.commit()
        return User(email = attrs.get('email'))
    except Exception ,e:
        transaction.rollback()
        print repr(e)
```

JSON I'm passing

```
data = {'email':'123@gmail.com,
        'password' : 'dummy',
        'userA' :   {'name' :'123'},
        'userB':{'type':1,'cost':'100'}
```

Whenever am making a POST request the 'attrs' gets only email and password not userA and userB, why? How can I deserialize and create data serially in the respective tables.

Comment: Can you include the POST request code?

Comment: @WAF am making request through ajax, do you want me to copy the function?

Answer (score 1):

try this in your view

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
import json

response = json.dumps(data,cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
return HttpResponse(response, mimetype="application/json")
```

and in success function you can access using

```
usera_name = response.userA.name
userb_type = response.userB.type
userb_cost = response.userB.cost
```